# Flutter make vertical appBar

Tags: flutter, appbar

In app I want to make a vertical appBar with custom title in different page:

[image]

How I can make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RotatedBox` to rotate `AppBar`, but you will not be able to use the parameter of `appBar` in `Scaffold`, because that one expects horizontal one.

```
class VerticalAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RotatedBox(
      quarterTurns: 3,
      child: AppBar(
        primary: false,
        title: Text('My Bar'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```